# Changing Low Frequency to High Frequency

Tags: frequency

Is there any kind of circuit that could take 60Hz and completely change it to some higher frequency using ONLY inductors, capacitors, and resistors?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_mixer

Comment: I don't think so.  You need some sort of non-linearity to change frequency.  Are we talking about idealized components or the real world?

Comment: Can diodes be added to the mix? Also, is output waveform a concern?

Comment: No.  You need nonlinear elements to add harmonics to 60Hz sine wave.  Basically, what @GuySirton wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the lack of requirement detail in the question, here is a frequency doubler circuit block that uses only capacitors and diodes to double the source frequency any number of times. The question does not specify voltage, load current, desired waveform, or relationship between input and output frequencies, so those factors are ignored for this answer.

I've taken the liberty to arbitrarily add diodes to the mix, since the question takes the liberty of being pretty arbitrary anyway.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjkbyz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each [bridge rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_bridge#Basic_operation) is just 4 diodes.

Comment: Here's a paper that talks about diode frequency doublers: http://www.techlib.com/files/diodedbl.pdf